# Permission denied when uninstalling numpy with pip

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to uninstall Numpy via Pip but this error comes up:

```
$ pip uninstall numpy

Uninstalling numpy:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.6.2-py2.7.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? y
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 54, in run
    requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 899, in uninstall
    req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 495, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1518, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 293, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    os.unlink(src)
 OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.6.2-py2.7.egg-info'
```

No clue what the best way to proceed from here would be. I would like to uninstall numpy completely then reinstall.

Comment: `sudo pip uninstall numpy`. When installing though you should really be using a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest).

Comment: But seriously, you don't have the proper permissions to delete the files, so you might want to try running `sudo pip unintsall numpy`

Comment: You might also find that `numpy` has been installed from `apt-get install python-numpy`, in which case you'll probably want to uninstall it via that route

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
sudo pip uninstall numpy
```

or, if it doesn't work:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-numpy
```

Comment: Did the first option, now I'm in a weird situation: If I try to uninstall again, the terminal says I can't do that because there's no Numpy package installed. However, if I run the python interpreter (by typing 'python' into the terminal) and try to import numpy, it is successful... So is numpy actually uninstalled or not?!

Comment: sudo pip uninstalls package from sudo python. check version sudo python and python it  must point two different versions of python.

Comment: or `sudo apt-get remove python3-numpy` :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add sudo, `sudo pip uninstall numpy`

Answer (score -3):

I did try several things, the following update works for me.

```
sudo easy_install -U numpy
```